# How can I use javascript to allow user to select a check box automatically when clicking a link to contact form?

Tags: javascript, forms, select

A link on my page visits the contact form. There are 3 links to the contact form, and I would like each link to autoselect a respective check box.

Like this:

LINK 1
-> user clicks -> visits contact page -> javascript embedded in the link autoselects checkbox next to "link one" text on the contact page

LINK 2
-> user clicks -> visits contact page -> javascript embedded in the link autoselects checkbox next to "link two" text on the contact page

LINK 3
-> user clicks -> visits contact page -> javascript embedded in the link autoselects checkbox next to "link three" text on the contact page

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do two things:

1. Add hashes to links, so links will look like this:
   http://www.yoursite.com/contact.html#link1,
   http://www.yoursite.com/contact.html#link2,
   http://www.yoursite.com/contact.html#link3, etc.
2. Add onDomReady/onload event handler that checks for window.location.hash
   property and performs the appropriate action based on its value

EDIT: Here's [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucgUr/) of what I mean.